# onreadystatechange undefined error

Tags: javascript, ajax

For over an hour now, I have been trying to debug my code but no dice. I realize that the asynchronous call of ajax means I have to make use of the callback function with the onreadystatechange event. The thing is, I keep getting the "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function xmlhttp.onreadystatechange" message in my console. What is wrong with my code? I am following the template on http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_suggest_php and I see no difference.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
   if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    document.getElementbyId("table").innerHTML = "Test";
   }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "bookstore.php?filename=bookstore.json", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only problem I see is that `getElementbyId` should be `getElementById` (capital `B`)

Comment: @Kevin please accept answers that solve your problem

Comment: I have been trying, but I have to wait 1 min